# Appending to every arg in variadic C macro

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to create a macro that works like the "where" constraint in higher-level languages:

```
#define where(T, ...) typename std::enable_if< /* tricky part */ >::type 
// should expand like so: trait1<T>::value && trait2<T>::value ... traitN<T>::value
```

So that **VA_ARGS** is list of traits and is used like so:

```
template<class T,
    where(T, std::is_default_constructible, std::is_class)>
class A { };
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe use [`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction)? You may need an intermediate trait that receives the type list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to bring this question back from the dead after four years, but I think I have a better answer that does exactly what I was aiming for at the time. (Not needing to specify the argument for the predicates multiple times.)

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class... Predicates>
using where_t = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<Predicates<T>...>>;

template <typename T, typename = where_t<T, std::is_default_constructible, std::is_class>>
struct my_struct
{
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
#define WHERE(P, ...) join_predicate<P, __VA_ARGS__>::value

template <template <typename> typename Pred, typename ...Args>
struct join_predicate : std::conjunction<Pred<Args>...> {};
```

Usage:

```
std::enable_if_t<WHERE(std::is_default_constructible, Foo, Bar, Quz), int>
```

I would probably not even bother with the macro and just use a real C++ construct, maybe:

```
template <template <typename> typename P, typename ...Args>
constexpr bool where_v = join_predicate<P, Args...>::value;
```